# Why is there no link to the rejection report when validating online gift aid submissions

Tags: gift-aid-extension

When I try to submit a gift aid claim it tells me there are two errors, but for some reason there is no link to the rejection report.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gift Aid is not part of CiviCRM core, so that message and functionality is the responsibility of the extension. You probably want to post your question to the extensions issue queue, as an enhancement request (and thank them for providing the extension while you're there).

My best guess is that you're using this extension: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/ukgiftaid

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue but managed to fix it by running the template report for 'Gift Aid Submission failure report' (under Reports - Contribution Report Templates) once and saving a copy as "GiftAid online failure". The report then appeared as necessary on the actual batch validation as well as on the overall online submission page.